# Добавить отмену действия в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Не так давно начал работать в tkinter. Хочу реализовать отмену действия при рисовании на canvas'e (на подобие undo/redo).Подскажите, какие-либо готовые реализации для этой GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def change_color():
    root['bg'] = "black"


class ImageGenerator:
    def __init__(self, parent, posx, posy, width, height,*kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.width =  width
        self.height = height
        self.sizex = 400
        self.sizey = 400
        self.b1 = "up"
        self.xold = None
        self.yold = None
        self.x_current = posx
        self.y_current = posy
        self.drawing_area=tk.Canvas(self.parent,
                                    width=self.width * 0.85,
                                    height=self.height * 0.93)
        self.drawing_area.place(x=self.posx, y=self.posy)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)
            
        self.button_fill = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="Fill",
                                    width=10, 
                                    bg='white',
                                     command=self.flood_fill)
        self.button_fill.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=70)

        self.button_clear = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                     text="Clear", 
                                     width=10,bg='white', 
                                     command=self.clear)
        self.button_clear.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=100)

        self.button_select_target = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                             text="Select Target",
                                             width=10,bg='white',
                                             command=self.select_target)
        self.button_select_target.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=40)

        self.button_line = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="Line",
                                    width=10,bg='white',
                                    command=self.line)
        self.button_line.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=10)

        self.button_back = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="back",
                                    width=5,bg='white',
                                    command=self.undo)
        self.button_back.place(x=self.width*0.875, y=self.height*0.90)

        self.button_next = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                     text="next",
                                     width=5, bg='white',
                                     command=self.line)
        self.button_next.place(x=self.width*0.94, y=self.height*0.90)

        self.image = Image.new("RGB",
                              (self.width, self.height), 
                              (255, 255, 255))
        self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

    def undo(self):
        pass

    def show_warning(self, msg):
        mb.showwarning("Предупреждение", msg)
        self.line()

    def line(self):
        self.drawing_area.place(x=self.posx, y=self.posy)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)

    def fill(self, img_gray, start_coords, fill_value):

        xsize, ysize = img_gray.shape
        orig_value = img_gray[start_coords[0], start_coords[1]]

        stack = set(((start_coords[0], start_coords[1]),))

        if fill_value == orig_value:
            self.show_warning("Вы попали маркером в границу контура")
            return False

        while stack:
            x, y = stack.pop()

            if img_gray[x, y] == orig_value:
                img_gray[x, y] = fill_value
                if x > 0:
                    stack.add((x - 1, y))
                    self.drawing_area.create_line(x-1,
                                                    y,
                                                    x-1,
                                                    y,
                                                    width=3,
                                                    fill='black')

                if x < (xsize - 1):
                    stack.add((x + 1, y))
                if y > 0:
                    stack.add((x, y - 1))
                if y < (ysize - 1):
                    stack.add((x, y + 1))

                if x == (xsize - 1) or y == (ysize - 1):
                    self.show_warning("Выбранный контур не замкнут")
                    return False
        return True

    def rgb2gray(self, rgb):
        return np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])


    def flood_fill(self):
        color = 0
        img_gray = self.rgb2gray(np.uint8(self.image))

        flag_fill = self.fill(img_gray,
                             (self.y_current, self.x_current),
                             color)

        im = np.asarray(img_gray)
        self.image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(im))
        # self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        # background_label = tk.Label(self.drawing_area, image=self.image)
        # background_label.place(x=700, y=400, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        # self.drawing_area.pack()
        if flag_fill:
            plt.imshow(img_gray, 'gray')
            plt.show()
        


    def select_target(self):
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.point)


    def clear(self):
        self.drawing_area.delete("all")
        self.image = Image.new("RGB", 
                              (self.width, self.height),
                              (255, 255, 255))
        self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.line()

    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1 = "down"

    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1 = "up"
        self.xold = None
        self.yold = None

    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1 == "down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                create_line = event.widget.create_line(self.xold,
                                         self.yold,
                                         event.x,
                                         event.y,
                                         smooth='true',
                                         width=3,
                                         fill='black')

                self.draw.line(((self.xold,self.yold),(event.x,event.y)),(0,0,0),width=3)
        self.xold = event.x
        self.yold = event.y

    def point(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.x_current = x
        self.y_current = y
        radius = 2
        x_max = x + radius
        x_min = x - radius
        y_max = y + radius
        y_min = y - radius

        circle = self.drawing_area.create_oval(x_max,
                                               y_max, 
                                               x_min, 
                                               y_min, 
                                               fill="black")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    width = 700
    height = 400
    pos_x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2 - width/2
    pos_y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2 - height/2
    root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, pos_x, pos_y))
    root.config(bg='white')
    ImageGenerator(root, 10, 10, width, height)
    change_color()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Например, можно записывать выполненные действия в список, для отмены полностью очищать холст, потом выполнять все действия кроме последнего. Чтобы не выполнять все действия, можно периодически делать "снимок" холста, и запоминать несколько действий после снимка (при отмене отображать на холсте "снимок" и записанные действия кроме последнего).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from undoredo import History


def change_color():
    root['bg'] = "black"


class ImageGenerator:
    def __init__(self, parent, posx, posy, width, height, *kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.width =  width
        self.height = height
        self.sizex = 400
        self.sizey = 400
        self.b1 = "up"
        self.xold = None
        self.yold = None
        self.x_current = posx
        self.y_current = posy
        self.flag = True
        self.history = []
        self.list_point = []
        self.list_line = []
        self.lines = []
        self.ff = []
        self.last_line = []
        self.bb = []
        self.drawing_area=tk.Canvas(self.parent,
                                    width=self.width * 0.85,
                                    height=self.height * 0.93)
        self.drawing_area.place(x=self.posx, y=self.posy)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)
            
        self.button_fill = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="Fill",
                                    width=10, 
                                    bg='white',
                                     command=self.flood_fill)
        self.button_fill.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=70)

        self.button_clear = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                     text="Clear", 
                                     width=10,bg='white', 
                                     command=self.clear)
        self.button_clear.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=100)

        self.button_select_target = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                             text="Select Target",
                                             width=10,bg='white',
                                             command=self.select_target)
        self.button_select_target.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=40)

        self.button_line = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="Line",
                                    width=10,bg='white',
                                    command=self.line)
        self.button_line.place(x=self.width*0.88, y=10)

        self.button_back = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                    text="back",
                                    width=5,bg='white',
                                    command=self.undo)
        self.button_back.place(x=self.width*0.875, y=self.height*0.90)

        self.button_next = tk.Button(self.parent,
                                     text="next",
                                     width=5, bg='white',
                                     command=self.redo)
        self.button_next.place(x=self.width*0.94, y=self.height*0.90)

        self.image = Image.new("RGB",
                              (self.width, self.height), 
                              (255, 255, 255))
        self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

    def undo(self):
        if len(History.history(self)) != 0:
            dict_point = History.history(self).pop()
            History.points(self, dict_point["history"])
            self.drawing_area.delete(dict_point["circle"])

        elif len(History.show_lines(self)) != 0: 
            # self.drawing_area.delete(dict_point1['line'])
            last_ln = self.last_line.pop(0)
            self.bb.append(last_ln)
            for el in range(last_ln, 0, -1):
                try:
                    dict_point1 = History.show_lines(self).pop()
                    History.lines(self, dict_point1["history"])
                    self.drawing_area.delete(el)
                except IndexError:
                    pass

    def redo(self):
        if len(History.show_points(self)) != 0:
            dict_point = History.show_points(self).pop()
            circle = self.drawing_area.create_oval(dict_point[0],
                                                   dict_point[1],
                                                   dict_point[2],
                                                   dict_point[3],
                                                   fill=dict_point[4])
        elif len(History.lines_show(self)) != 0:
            dict_point1 = History.lines_show(self)
            i=0
            vv = self.bb.pop(0)
            for el in dict_point1:
                if i == vv:
                    break
                else:
                    create_line = self.drawing_area.create_line(el[0],
                                                                el[1],
                                                                el[2],
                                                                el[3],
                                                                smooth='true',
                                                                width=3,
                                                                fill='black')
                    self.draw.line(((el[0], el[1]), (el[2], el[3])), el[4], width=el[5])
        History.show_lines(self).clear()

    def show_warning(self, msg):
        mb.showwarning("Предупреждение", msg)
        self.line()

    def line(self):
        self.drawing_area.place(x=self.posx, y=self.posy)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)

    def fill(self, img_gray, start_coords, fill_value):

        xsize, ysize = img_gray.shape
        orig_value = img_gray[start_coords[0], start_coords[1]]

        stack = set(((start_coords[0], start_coords[1]),))

        if fill_value == orig_value:
            self.show_warning("Вы попали маркером в границу контура")
            return False

        while stack:
            x, y = stack.pop()

            if img_gray[x, y] == orig_value:
                img_gray[x, y] = fill_value
                if x > 0:
                    stack.add((x - 1, y))
                    self.drawing_area.create_line(x-1,
                                                    y,
                                                    x-1,
                                                    y,
                                                    width=3,
                                                    fill='black')

                if x < (xsize - 1):
                    stack.add((x + 1, y))
                if y > 0:
                    stack.add((x, y - 1))
                if y < (ysize - 1):
                    stack.add((x, y + 1))

                if x == (xsize - 1) or y == (ysize - 1):
                    self.show_warning("Выбранный контур не замкнут")
                    return False
        return True

    def rgb2gray(self, rgb):
        return np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

    def flood_fill(self):
        color = 0
        img_gray = self.rgb2gray(np.uint8(self.image))

        flag_fill = self.fill(img_gray,
                             (self.y_current, self.x_current),
                             color)

        im = np.asarray(img_gray)
        self.image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(im))
        # self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        if flag_fill:
            plt.imshow(img_gray, 'gray')
            plt.show()

    def select_target(self):
        self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.point)

    def clear(self):
        self.drawing_area.delete("all")
        self.image = Image.new("RGB", 
                              (self.width, self.height),
                              (255, 255, 255))
        self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.line()

    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1 = "down"
        self.flag = True

    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1 = "up"
        self.xold = None
        self.yold = None
        self.flag = False
        try:
            self.last_line.append(self.ff[-1])
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1 == "down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                create_line = event.widget.create_line(self.xold,
                                         self.yold,
                                         event.x,
                                         event.y,
                                         smooth='true',
                                         width=3,
                                         fill='black')

                self.draw.line(((self.xold,self.yold),(event.x,event.y)),(0,0,0),width=3)
                # self.history.append(create_line)
                dict_line = {"line":create_line, "history":[self.xold, self.yold, event.x, event.y, (0,0,0), 3]}
                History.register_lines(self, dict_line)
                self.ff.append(create_line)


        self.xold = event.x
        self.yold = event.y

    def point(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.x_current = x
        self.y_current = y
        radius = 2
        x_max = x + radius
        x_min = x - radius
        y_max = y + radius
        y_min = y - radius

        circle = self.drawing_area.create_oval(x_max,
                                               y_max, 
                                               x_min, 
                                               y_min, 
                                               fill="black")
        dict_history_point = {"circle": circle, "history": [x_max, y_max, x_min, y_min, "black"]}
        History.register(self, dict_history_point)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    width = 700
    height = 400
    pos_x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2 - width/2
    pos_y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2 - height/2
    root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, pos_x, pos_y))
    root.config(bg='white')
    ImageGenerator(root, 10, 10, width, height)
    change_color()
    root.mainloop()
```

Файл undoredo

```
class History:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []
        self.list_line = []
        self.list_point = []
        self.lines = []

    def history(self):
        return self.history

    def register(self, command):
        self.history.append(command)

    def register_lines(self, line):
        self.list_line.append(line)

    def lines(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def lines_show(self):
        return self.lines

    def show_lines(self):
        return self.list_line

    def points(self, point):
        self.list_point.append(point)

    def show_points(self):
        return self.list_point
```